# Celery Why Does Task Stay In Queue

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

So I am using Celery with RabbitMQ. I have a RESTful API that registers a user. I am using remote Celery worker to send a registration email asynchronously so my API can return fast response.

```
from .tasks import send_registration_email

def register_user(user_data):
    # save user to the database etc

    send_registration_email.delay(user.id)

    return {'status': 'success'}
```

This works fine. Email is being sent in a non blocking asynchronous way (and can be retried if fails which is cool). The problem is when I look at RabbitMQ management console. I can see that the send_registration_email has created a random queue. Something like:

[image]

I can see that the task has been successfully executed. So why does the random queue stays in RabbitMQ forever? This is the task payload:

```
{"status": "SUCCESS", "traceback": null, "result": true, "task_id": "aad10877-3508-4179-a5fb-99f1bd0b8b2f", "children": []}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This normal behaviour, if you have configured CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND in your settings. Please check here: [Celery result backend description](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-result-backend)

You could disable result backend, or decrease each message life time.

Comment: Yep. I have figured this out in the meantime. I have added ignore_result=True to the task annotations. Is it a good practise to ignore results? I have lots of tasks that don't return any results (lots of tasks for sending emails, log rotations, reporting and maintenance tasks etc) so I am ignore results from them.

Comment: Do you read any results in other RabbitMQ tasks? In this case deleting RESULT_BACKEND is better solution I think.

Comment: I do have tasks from which I read results so I cannot just turn off result backend. Actually my whole SOA is running on AMQP. Instead of SOAP my services talk to each other over RabbitMQ / Celery.